# Is Azure AD Conditional Access supported for Dynamics 365 web services?

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-online

The Dynamics 365 web services SDK uses ADAL for authentication. I have setup a service account with access to perform some administration in Dynamics CRM Online. I have also setup an Azure AD conditional access policy to IP restrict access for this service account. The service account is still able to connect with Dynamics 365 web services from a blocked IP address. I have verified that the service account is not able to log in to O365 from the same using web browser after applying the policy. I have also verified that the rule takes affect using the AAD what-if tool.

So it seems AAD Conditional Access is not supported for Dynamics 365 web services. Is this true? The value of AAD conditional access diminishes in this scenario if it is true, but at least I am able to restrict use of the UI from any other IP.

Comment: I would open a support ticket, because it is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/restrict-access-online-trusted-ip-rules. You either have a configuration issue or there is a bug. There should not be a difference between hitting the server to get HTML or a SOAP response (or WebApi JSON reapone.)

Comment: Thanks I will do that.

My access policy includes all cloud apps and only that user. It blocks access to all locations except for the trusted ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing worth mentioning is that Conditional Access (CA) Policies are only applicable on `user account`. This is described in the FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-faqs (search for service account)

If you use a `user account` as service account, then the CA will apply. CAs currently do not apply on service principals. You can use [Certificate authentication for service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal) to make the authentication stronger. But in general, currently CA is only available to `user accounts`.

Comment: Thanks. Certificate authentication for service principal is worth looking into as an alternative to user account with CA.

Microsoft is looking into the issue with CA not applying in this case.

Comment: I am not sure if your last sentence is a question or a statement. If it is a question - sorry I cannot answer that, I am not part of the product team. But I hope it is so :) My personal speculation is that service principal with certificate login is good enough to protect resources. If there is a leak of private key there is serious security breach and no CA will help in that case (in order to get the private key of certificate one must be in the network. If he/she is in the network you have other problems...).

Comment: It was a statement. We have a support ticket with the Dynamics 365 team and another with the AAD team on the issue. I have had several sessions with them. They are working together to give us an answer.

For an AAD integration we've done using the Graph API, we use Client Credentials Flow with certificate authentication. That is not possible here because there is no way to give the client access in the CRM instance. I have not tried with a service principal yet. I have asked Microsoft for a security recommendation on authentication with the Dynamics 365 web services.

Comment: And [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/create-users-assign-online-security-roles#create-an-application-user) and [that](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/joegilldynamicscrm/archive/2017/12/12/how-to-configure-dynamics-365-s2s-authentication) (with certificate instead of symmetric key) do not help?

Comment: Yes, this will help. Here is a GitHub project with c# code to connect to the Dynamics 365 web services using certificate. It also has a powershell script that automates creating self signed certificate, the application and the security principal: https://github.com/mariusagur/msdyn365-certificate-auth

Comment: I got Client Credentials Flow with certificate authentication to work for the Dynamics 365 web services. I used the same Enterprise Application that we use for the Graph API. There were lots of problems to figure out to make it work. With the exception of these two, solutions were available online:
1. ADAL v2.22.302111727 must be used with XRM SDK v9.0.2.4. We used a later version of ADAL. The SDK responded with the very helpful message: Unable to Login to Dynamics CRMOrganizationServiceProxy is null.

Comment: 2. I had to impersonate a user with read access to the private key of the certificate when getting it from the store. For the Graph API it is sufficient if the IIS app pool identity has read access to the private key. Our web application impersonates the logged in user.

Comment: I have asked the Microsoft team if Client Credentials Flow with Certificate Authentication is best practice for daemon applications. Do you have thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, you have THE answer to your original question. I will refrain from more comments.

Comment: Microsoft has replied as follows:
CRM SDK method used (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602970.aspx) uses SAML protocol, instead of OAuth2, and this legacy Authentication method is not supported by Azure AD Conditional Access (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azure-portal).